# Loading data form DataTable to SPGridview C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, datatable, spgridview

I'm making some webparts for myself and I want to populate SPGridview with some data.

```
DataTable table = /*some data*/;
SPGridview grid = new SPGridview();

// setting up SPGridview properties 

grid.DataSource = table;
grid.DataBind();
```

When I did that with GirdView it worked just fine. But when I tried to do that with SPGridview my webpart shows just blank page. I suppose that SPGridview need a little more from my side and if you could give me tip how to do it.

Comment: P.S. Assume that I don't know structure of data in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Microsoft disabled AutoGenerateColumns property and I don't know how to bypass without using a loop. Here is a working code:

```
        SPGridView _gridview = new SPGridView();
        DataTable table = /*some data*/;

        _gridview.Enabled = true;
        _gridview.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _gridview.Visible = true;

        foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            SPBoundField field = new SPBoundField();
            field.DataField = col.ColumnName;
            _gridview.Columns.Add(field);
        }

        _gridview.DataSource = table;
        _gridview.DataBind();

        this.Controls.Add(_gridview);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        SPGridView myGridView = new SPGridView();
        myGridView.Enabled = true;

        myGridView.DataSource = table;
        myGridView.DataBind();


       this.Controls.Add(myGridView);
```

Try this code............

Comment: Thanks for last line I forgot about that SPGridView it's not auto-generated control and need to be added.